# Python : How to remove microseconds from django timestamp?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cookiecutter-django

In PostgreSQL database `timestamp` datatype column has value as:

```
2018-06-08 12:35:09
```

But when retrieving data using django, data is returned as (datetime is combining microseconds):

```
"2018-06-08T12:35:09.225"
```

How can I convert this datetime object to "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS" format in django?

**Note** - I am using CookieCutter

Code I am using to retrieve data from Model `Bid` is as below (`views.py`):

```
request_data = json.loads(request.body)
bidId = request_data['id']
bidData = Bid.objects.get(bid_id=bidId)
data = serializers.serialize('json', [bidData, ])
serialized = json.loads(data)
bid_obj = json.loads(serialized[0]['fields']['bid_obj'])
serialized[0]['fields']['bid_obj'] = bid_obj
outputArray = {
    "bid": serialized[0]['fields']
}
return JsonResponse(outputArray, safe=False)
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the timezone? I'd rather say it is the microseconds.

Comment: does not look right, django added microseconds?

Comment: @cezar, may be its microseconds, Sorry but I am new to django. Updated Post.

Comment: @BearBrown, Yes Bro. I am fetching data from model only.

Comment: show, please, how do you get data from postgres

Comment: Don't worry, it wasn't meant to belittle you. We have to clarify the issue first. We have to assure that everybody really understands the problem. Naive answer would be `yourdatetimevariable.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')`.

Comment: Please don't mix **snake_case** (`bid_obj`) and **camelCase** (`bidData`). It's a terrible practice. Follow Python conventions and use **snake_case** for naming variables, correctly and consistently throughout your whole project.

Comment: @cezar Sure, I will.

Comment: @cezar, Post your code as answer please, It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found out, the `datetime` object that is retrieved contains microseconds. If you don't want to display the microseconds, or any other part of the `datetime` object, you can use the method `strftime` and pass the desired format.

In your case the desired format is **DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS**. You can get that format in python with the following snippet:

```
dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

It is assumed that the variable `dt` is a `datetime` object.

In the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) you can see which other options you can pass to `strftime`.